# When is a matrix times its transpose commutative

Tags: matrices

Let $M$ be a $n \times n$ matrix,
given that $M M^\mathrm T$ = $ M^\mathrm T M$,
is it true that $M = Q + kI$ where $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix, $k$ is a scalar and $I$ is the unit matrix.

Most likely it is false, then I may ask when is $M M^\mathrm T$ = $ M^\mathrm T M$ true?

Comment: You might like to read about [normal matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix).